# How to pass value in html table tag

Tags: php, mysql

In my side project I have a list of song titles and keys that I'm pulling from my database and I'm just wondering how can I use that with an HTML table.

I've been playing around inside the `<table>` but still no luck so I would be really appreciate if I can get any help or suggestion.

[image]

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Chord</th>
  </tr>

// it will display all the title and chord from here
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Key E</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<?php
    foreach ($songTitle as $song) {
        echo "<a href='details.php?id={$song['id']}'>{$song['title']} {$song['chord']}   <br> </a>";
} ?>
```

Comment: Just echo the html the same way as you are echoing the href html.

Comment: Hi @droopsnoot I update the post with pic so can you pls check again for me?. thanks

Comment: See the answer from RiggsFolly below. Just output the table tags around the data.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to output the table row in the foreach loop, then just use the 2 values in the 2 `<td></td>` cell definitions

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Chord</th>
  </tr>

// it will display all the title and chord from here
?php
foreach ($songTitle as $song) :
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $song['title'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $song['chord']; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php
endforeach;
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what are you looking for

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Chord</th>
      </tr>
     
      <tr>
        <td>Example Title</td>
        <td>Key E</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
    // display the song title and chord
    <?php
              foreach ($songTitle as $song) {

      <tr>
        
      
               echo "<td>{$song['title']}</td><td><a href='details.php?id={$song['id']}'>{$song['title']} {$song['chord']}    </a></td>";
</tr>
    } ?>
```

Comment: Hi Jack, sorry if my question is not clear. What I really wanted is based on the screenshot that I just posted. (post updated). can you pls check again for me?. thanks

Comment: This code isn't correct - you close the table before you start outputting table elements.